# How to correct my design to avoid circular dependency

Tags: php, laravel, architecture, solid-principles

I'm banging my head to find a solution to this but still i'm unable, I'm looking for a design vice solution not a hack to fix the issue.

I have following classes

```
class CourseService{

     public function getCourse($courceId){
         $course = $this->courseRepo->getCourse($courseId);
         $restrictions = $this->invoiceService->getRestrictions($course->courseid);
         $course->restrictions = [];
         if($restrictions != null){
           $course->restrictions = $restrictions;
         }
     }
}
```

1. Now this course service is injected in the constructor of the `StudentService` because when students need to enroll to a cource i use this course service there.
2. also you can see that I have used `CourseRepo` to get Course object and then `InvoiceService` to say which fields are restricted to update, basically `restrictions` attributes gives an array of strings defining which fields are not allowed to edit and I expect UI developer will use it to disable those fields, and I had to inject `InvoiceService` because there are some processing to do to the raw db records that are fetched from the `InvoiceRepo` so invoice repo is encapsulated in the invoiceService

now lets look at the InvoiceService

```
Class InvoiceService{

    public function getAmountToPay($courseid, $studentid){
         //now I need to inject StduentService inorder to get student info which needed for the calculation
    }
}
```

3. but I can't inject StudentService into here because `StudentService` -> `CourceService` -> `InvoiceService`

### Options I see and the consequences

1. One option I see is to get rid of `InvoiceService` from the `CourseService` and use `InvoiceService` in the place where the `getCourse()` get called and then modify the result but the problem is, `CourseService` is used mainly in controllers and next thing is that getCourse() get called from many controllers and service and expects the restrictions to be there so if I want to get rid of the `InvoiceService` then I'll have many places to add the removing lines and it crates a code repetition.
2. I can move getAmountToPay() to student service but then that service has already doing many student related tasks and i'm happy to extract just the invoice part to another service so I have a clear place to look when I need to check for bugs on invoices.

Comment: By the way, did you saw that the veriable that you accept in the function has a typo? I bet you ment `$courseId` and not `$courceId`.

Comment: hi this is just an abstract code just to explain my situation.

Answer (score 1):

**Student service:**

First of all you have to see - actually to decide - that a **student service** uses an **invoice service**, not the reciprocal. When I enroll myself as a history student, I go to the registration/students office first. They are calling the financial/invoice office to ask about how much should I pay. The financial office checks in the database and returns the response regarding the amount to be payed by me.

**Course service:**

...The time passed by. Now I'm a student. I don't need to go to the registration office anymore. If I have to know something about my courses I go to the secretariat/**course service**. They'll give me all the informations I need about my courses. But, if I want to visit some special archeology course, where one must pay something, the course service will call the financial/**invoice service** to ask about that for me. They, in turn, will return the infos. The same applies if the course service wants to know about some financial restrictions I should have: they call the financial/invoice service.

**Invoice service - student service, invoice service - course service:**

Now, what should happen, if the invoice service needs infos about a student or a course? Should it call the student service, or the course service for that? The answer is no. The invoice service should receive a student id, a course id, a domain object Student, or a domain object Course as constructor/methods dependencies, but not the corresponding service(s). And it will fetch the infos it needs by itself. More of it, the invoice service should work with its specific invoice/financial tables, not with the course tables or the student details tables (except their id's).

**Conclusions:**

- To enroll a student is the job of the StudentService. Though the
  CourseService can assist the enrollment process.
- StudentService verifies the amount to be paid by a student by calling
  the InvoiceService. I know you don't want to have `getAmountToPay()`
  inside the StudentService, but it's a natural workflow. You may think
  of separate the other many things, for which the StudentService is
  responsible, to another services.
- The CourseService is responsible for finding a course, together with
  the course restrictions, for which it calls the InvoiceService. So,
  the CourseService will be assisted by the InvoiceService.

Down under I passed you the PHP version of my vision. I renamed some functions, to give you a better perspective.

Good luck!

P.S: I hope I understood right, that the sense of "invoice sevice" is a "financial department" one. Sorry, but I'm not a native english speaker, so I can't know all the senses.

```
<?php

class StudentService {

    protected $courseService;
    protected $invoiceService;

    /**
     * Even if the course service uses the invoice service,
     * doesn't mean that the student service shouldn't use it too.
     * 
     * @param CourseService $courseService
     * @param InvoiceService $invoiceService
     */
    public function __construct(CourseService $courseService, InvoiceService $invoiceService) {
        $this->courseService = $courseService;
        $this->invoiceService = $invoiceService;
    }

    /**
     * Enroll a student to a course.
     * 
     * @param integer $studentId
     * @param integer $courseId
     * @return bool Enrolled or not.
     */
    public function enrollToCourse($studentId, $courseId) {
        //... Use here the CourseService too - for what you said regarding the enrollment.
        $enrolled = $this->studentRepo->enrollToCourse($studentId, $courseId);
        return $enrolled;
    }

    /**
     * Get the amount to be payed by a student on the enrollment moment.
     * 
     * @param integer $studentId
     * @param integer $courseid
     * @return integer Amount to be payed.
     */
    public function getAmountToPayOnEnrollment($studentId, $courseid) {
        $amount = $this->invoiceService->getAmountToPayOnEnrollment($studentId, $courseid);
        return $amount;
    }

}

class CourseService {

    protected $invoiceService;

    /**
     * Invoice service is used to get the (financial) restrictions for a course.
     * 
     * @param InvoiceService $invoiceService
     */
    public function __construct(InvoiceService $invoiceService) {
        $this->invoiceService = $invoiceService;
    }

    /**
     * Get a course and its corresponding (financial) restrictions list.
     *  
     * @param integer $courseId
     * @return Course Course domain object.
     */
    public function getCourse($courseId) {
        $course = $this->courseRepo->getCourse($courseId);
        $course->restrictions = $this->getRestrictionsForCourse($course->courseId);
        return $course;
    }

    /**
     * Get the (financial) restrictions for a specified course.
     * 
     * @param integer $courseId
     * @return array Restrictions list.
     */
    public function getRestrictionsForCourse($courseId) {
        $restrictions = $this->invoiceService->getRestrictionsForCourse($courseId);
        return $restrictions;
    }

}

Class InvoiceService {

    /**
     * No student service needed!
     */
    public function __construct() {
        //...
    }

    /**
     * Again, no student service needed: the invoice service
     * fetches by itself the needed infos from the database.
     * 
     * Get the amount to be payed by a student on the enrollment moment.
     * 
     * @param integer $studentId
     * @param integer $courseid
     * @return integer Amount to be payed.
     */
    public function getAmountToPayOnEnrollment($studentId, $courseid) {
        $amount = $this->invoiceRepo->getAmountToPayOnEnrollment($studentId, $courseid);
        return $amount;
    }

    /**
     * Get the (financial) restrictions for a course.
     * 
     * @param integer $studentId
     * @param integer $courseid
     * @return array Restrictions list.
     */
    public function getRestrictionsForCourse($courseid) {
        $restrictions = $this->invoiceRepo->getRestrictionsForCourse($courseid);
        return isset($restrictions) ? $restrictions : [];
    }

    /*
     * Quote: "Some processing to do to the raw 
     * db records that are fetched from the InvoiceRepo".
     */
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your invoiceService to not depend on student service.   Pass in what you need to the invoiceService.  The logic of what to do with those student details can stay in invoiceService, but the content can be passed in.